# Display threshold line even if threshold value is higher than max y-axis value in HighStock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Click here for [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/surajcs009/w4akst20/1/)

```
 yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: thresholdvalue,
        color: 'green',
        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
        width: 2,
        label: {
          text: 'Last quarter minimum'
        }
      }]
    },
```

When I click on 1D range selector, threshold value is 19 but max value in y-axis is 15.7, that's why plotted threshold line is not shown.

Is it possible to display the threshold line in any case whether the threshold value is in the range or not.

Thanks, for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate minimum and maximum values for the Y axis for a given range including your threshold. And then pass `min` and `max` to the `yAxis.update()`.

**UPDATE:**

You can trigger range selection event when you handle the `load` event like this: `this.rangeSelector.clickButton(3)`, where `3` is the index of the button  you want to trigger (1 month in this case) in the range selector.

#### Working example:

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=large-dataset.json&callback=?', function(data) {

  // Create a timer
  var start = +new Date();
  var thresholdvalue = 30;
  var _fullData = data;

  // Create the chart
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          this.setTitle(null, {
            text: 'Built chart in ' + (new Date() - start) + 'ms'
          });
          this.rangeSelector.clickButton(3)
        }
      },
      zoomType: 'x'
    },

    rangeSelector: {

      buttons: [

        {
          type: 'day',
          count: 1,
          text: '1D'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 3,
          text: '3d'
        }, {
          type: 'week',
          count: 1,
          text: '1w'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 1,
          text: '1m'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 6,
          text: '6m'
        }, {
          type: 'year',
          count: 1,
          text: '1y'
        }, {
          type: 'all',
          text: 'All'
        }
      ],
      selected: 3
    },
    xAxis: {
      events: {
        setExtremes: function(e) {
          if (e.trigger == "rangeSelectorButton") {
            var series = this.chart.series[0];
            var yAxis = this.chart.yAxis[0];
            var threshold = thresholdvalue;
            
            //I can't see _fullData here without doing this
            var all_data = _fullData; 
            
            //Calculate values for a given range
            //Use floor() here, just to be sure that indeses passed to slice() are integers
            var values = all_data.data.slice(
              Math.floor((e.min - all_data.pointStart) / all_data.pointInterval),
                Math.floor((e.max - all_data.pointStart) / all_data.pointInterval) + 1 
            );
            //Add threshold value to the array
            values.push(thresholdvalue);
            //Calculate min and max including threshold
      let minY = Math.min.apply(null, values);
            let maxY = Math.max.apply(null, values);
            series.update({
              threshold: threshold
            }, false);
            yAxis.update({
              plotLines: [{
                //value: threshold,
                value: threshold,
                color: 'green',
                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                width: 2,
                visible: true,
                label: {
                  text: 'Last quarter minimum'
                }
              }],
              //Add min and max to the graph
              min: minY,
             max: maxY
            });
          }
        },
      }
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: thresholdvalue,
        color: 'green',
        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
        visible: true,
        width: 2,
        label: {
          text: 'Last quarter minimum'
        }
      }]
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Hourly temperatures in Vik i Sogn, Norway, 2009-2015'
    },

    subtitle: {
      text: 'Built chart in ...' // dummy text to reserve space for dynamic subtitle
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Temperature',
      data: data.data,
      pointStart: data.pointStart,
      pointInterval: 3600000,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 1,
        valueSuffix: '°C'
      },
      negativeColor: 'red',
      threshold: thresholdvalue
    }]

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

Comment: Dmitry, thanks for the answer but my question is more specific to display the threshold line in any case even if the value is large. For example: if threshold value in the beginning is 100, then threshold line is not displayed e.g. Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/w4akst20/2/

Comment: Got the logic, need to set minY and maxY. Thanks @Dmitry for the answer.